# What is the correct constant for the exit system call?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64

I am trying to learn x86_64 assembly, and am using GCC as my assembler. The exact command I'm using is:

```
gcc -nostdlib tapydn.S -D__ASSEMBLY__
```

I'm mainly using gcc for its preprocessor. Here is `tapydn.S`:

```
.global _start

#include <asm-generic/unistd.h>

syscall=0x80

.text
_start:
    movl $__NR_exit, %eax
    movl $0x00, %ebx
    int  $syscall
```

This results in a segmentation fault. I believe the problem is with the following line:

```
 movl $__NR_exit, %eax
```

I used `__NR_exit` because it was more descriptive than some magic number. However, it appears that my usage of it is incorrect. I believe this to be the case because when I change the line in question to the following, it runs fine:

```
movl $0x01, %eax
```

Further backing up this trail of thought is the contents of `usr/include/asm-generic/unistd.h`:

```
#define __NR_exit 93
__SYSCALL(__NR_exit, sys_exit)
```

I expected the value of __NR_exit to be 1, not 93! Clearly I am misunderstanding its purpose and consequently its usage. For all I know, I'm getting lucky with the `$0x01` case working (much like undefined behaviour in C++), so I kept digging...

Next, I looked for the definition of `sys_exit`. I couldn't find it. I tried using it anyway as follows (with and without the preceeding $):

```
movl $sys_exit, %eax
```

This wouldn't link:

```
/tmp/cc7tEUtC.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x1): undefined reference to `sys_exit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My guess is that it's a symbol in one of the system libraries and I'm not linking it due to my passing `-nostdlib` to GCC. I'd like to avoid linking such a large library for just one symbol if possible.

In response to Jester's comment about mixing 32 and 64 bit constants, I tried using the value `0x3C` as suggested:

```
movq $0x3C, %eax
movq $0x00, %ebx
```

This also resulting a segmentation fault. I also tried swapping out `eax` and `ebx` for `rax` and `rbx`:

```
movq $0x3C, %rax
movq $0x00, %rbx
```

The segmentation fault remained.

Jester then commented stating that I should be using `syscall` rather than `int $0x80`:

```
.global _start

#include <asm-generic/unistd.h>

.text
_start:
    movq $0x3C, %rax
    movq $0x00, %rbx
    syscall
```

This works, but I was later informed that I should be using `rdi` instead of `rbx` as per the System V AMD64 ABI:

```
movq $0x00, %rdi
```

This also works fine, but still ends up using the magic number `0x3C` for the system call number.

Wrapping up, my questions are as follows:

- What is the correct usage of `__NR_exit`?
- What should I be using instead of a magic number for the `exit` system call?

Comment: You are mixing 32 and 64 bit constants (they are not the same). Actually you are even using asm-generic which is entirely unrelated to either. The 32 bit constant is `1`, the 64 bit one is `60`.

Comment: @Jester thanks for the help! However I'm a little confused by this: I tried changing the value from `0x01` to `0x3C` and got a segmentation fault again. The command "file a.out" states that the executable is x86_64, what am I missing here?

Comment: 64 bit mode actually uses the `syscall` instruction, the `int 0x80` is the legacy 32 bit compatibility interface.

Comment: @Jester thanks, that worked! I've updated the question

Comment: Also, the 64 bit calling convention uses `rdi` to pass the exit code. See [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI).

Comment: @Jester thanks again, updated :)

Comment: Notice also in modern Linux `exit` is thread exit, `exit_group` is process exit (libc `exit()` calls the latter). More likely they will work identically in your case, but, in more complex setup, additional threads can appear.

Comment: @Netch noted, I'll use that instead then, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct header file to get the system call numbers is `sys/syscall.h`. The constants are called `SYS_###` where `###` is the name of the system call you are interested in. The `__NR_###` macros are implementation details and should not be used. As a rule of thumb, if an identifier begins with an underscore it should not be used, if it begins with two it should definitely not be used. The arguments go into `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `r10`, `r8`, and `r9`. Here is a sample program for Linux:

```
#include <sys/syscall.h>

    .globl _start
_start:
    mov $SYS_exit,%eax
    xor %edi,%edi
    syscall
```

These conventions are mostly portable to other UNIX-like operating systems.

Comment: On my 64-bit Ubuntu I found the file to be `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/syscall.h`.

Comment: @user2023370 This file is included from `sys/syscall.h`.  You should not include it directly.

Comment: This file is absent.

Comment: @user2023370 Try `echo '#include <sys/syscall.h>' | cc -E -`.  This shows you where `sys/syscall.h` is located.  On Linux systems using glibc, it's typically not in `/usr/include`.

Comment: Fair enough - for reference, the actual information on system call numbers is in the file at that location on Ubuntu. Nice little script, thanks.

Comment: @user2023370 The point of `sys/system.h` is to give you semi-portable macros for the system call numbers so you don't have to know what the specific number is in the first place.  The `bits/syscall.h` file is an implementation detail; while it contains the actual numbers, it should not be included directly because it is not part of the libc interface.

Comment: I seem to recall reading that `__NR_write` is just as stable as `SYS_write`, and maybe actually preferred, with the `SYS_` names being for backwards compat.  This may have just been some random person's opinion, but the `SYS_` macros are just defined in terms of the `__NR_` macros, with another level of includes.  `#include <asm/unistd.h>` gives you a portable way to include the right file with call numbers for the right ABI, detecting i386 vs. x86-64 vs. x32 for example on an x86 system.

Comment: @PeterCordes The `__NR_` macros are Linux only as opposed to the `SYS_` macros specified by SysV and POSIX. That's why the latter are more portable.

Comment: @user2023370: `locate asm/unistd_64.h` (or `unistd_32.h`) should find the actual file on an x86-64 Linux system wherever your distro puts it, if you want to look in it directly.  (On Arch GNU/Linux, it's `/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h`).  The other files just include one of those, which is fine if you're going to `#include` into your `.S` asm source or feed it to `cc -E -dM` to dump macros.