# Import constants in x86 with gas

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I have the following two files in assembly:

```
# file.s
.globl _start
_start:
    mov $10, %edi
    mov $SYS_EXIT, %eax
    syscall
```

```
# utils.s
SYS_EXIT    = 60
SYS_WRITE   = 1
SYS_STDOUT  = 1
```

What is required to be able to link these two files into an executable. To assemble and link I've tried doing:

```
$ as file.s -o file.o
$ as utils.s -o utils.o
$ ld utils.o file.o -o file 
# file.o: In function `_start':
# (.text+0x8): undefined reference to `SYS_EXIT'
```

Which seems to just mean I'm not properly importing the file/constants. What would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: @NateEldredge yes, thanks for noticing. Fixed

Comment: The most straightforward thing is just to have the assembler substitute the constants, not the linker.  For that you just need to include `utils.s` into `file.s`.  Use [`.include "utils.s"`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Include.html#Include), or change its name to `file.S`, compile with `gcc -c`, and use C preprocessor directives, `#include "utils.s"`.

Comment: @NateEldredge cool, thanks for the help. Out of curiosity, how would you do this in the linker, or is that way not really suggested?

Comment: You don't need to define the syscall numbers yourself.  `#include <asm/unistd.h>` to use the glibc / Linux headers (which only contain `#define __NR_write 1`, no C prototypes).  Name your asm source `foo.S` and build with `gcc -static -nostdlib foo.S -o foo`.  Also, your macros use the same naming scheme for system calls as they do for STDOUT_FILENO.  It's not a `SYS_` system-call number.

Comment: [What is the correct constant for the exit system call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41915010) covers that part.

Comment: Symbols are only visible to other object files if made global using a `.globl` directive.